# TypeError: this.$el.querySelector is not a function nuxt filepond

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, filepond

I have these codes

my template codes

```html
<no-ssr>
  <file-pond />
</no-ssr>
```

script codes for file-pond component

```js
// Create component
const FilePond = vueFilePond(FilePondPluginFileValidateType, FilePondPluginImagePreview)

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    FilePond
  },
  setup() {
...
```

and then I have this error

```
TypeError: this.$el.querySelector is not a function
    at VueComponent.mounted (vue-filepond.js?1501:123)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4235)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3158)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6390)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6609)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3963)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4075)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4570)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4326)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1989)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1915)
```

it seems like the file is running on server-side where DOM is not accessed but i don't know how actually to run this in client only , `<no-ssr>` and `client-only` are not working

Comment: Your code does not show anything relevant. Can you please provide more relevant info as of your code/setup? Btw, Nuxt is still using Vue2,

Comment: Should probably use vue-filepond@6

Comment: @Rik I have used this as a plugin instead, and i registered with `mode:client` and it works

Answer (score 0):

Go to `vue-filepond` GitHub repo, download the file stored in `lib/index.js`.
Put it somewhere in your codebase and edit the `mounted` function, change `this.$el.querySelector` to `document.querySelector`.

Then you can directly import this file instead of importing as a node_module:

```js
import vueFilePond from './file-pond.js'
```

Note: for Vue 2 use version 6.x of the plugin